# During the elections.. "on June 20 in 2016"?

Tags: dates

How can I correctly use a precise date to complete this sentence?

"During the elections on **June 20 in 2016**, the GB decided, ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply use a comma between the day and the year:

> During the elections **on June 20, 2016**, the GB decided [...]